# How can i make my program run faster: Is using threads a solution?

Tags: c#, performance

I've written a program building a huge search tree. Because my tree is too huge i expected that my program will use over 40 % of cpu. instead of this my program uses not over 10 % of cpu even it runs with high priority.

If threads will use more cpu while running parallel, let me please know it; i can divide my program in threads, i need really reduce the search time.

Thanks !

Comment: 10% is over how many cores? That *seems* a bit low - are you sure you don't have an IO bottleneck?

Comment: Probably your program isn't CPU bound, but bandwidth limited.

Comment: And you should never increase the priority of threads/programs that are using lots CPU, but rather *lower* it to make the system responsive.

Comment: 2 cores with 50 %, but my taskmanager may show wrong at performence and tasks tabs.

Answer (score 2):

> instead of this my program uses not over 10 % of cpu

How many processors do you have, and how is your OS measuring those 10% , i.e. some OS will show 10% usage if you have 10 processors and use 1 of them 100%.

However, in the case you're not utilizing a processor 100%, you need to figure out why. Perhaps it's somehow IO/network bound and you IO in an inefficient manner. You also mention it's "huge", so what does that mean ? If you really mean **huge**, and you're using up all the memory of your machine and you start swapping, performance goes down the drain, and you need to either find a more efficient algoritmh/memory use or get more ram.

> i can divide my program in threads

If your 1 thread doesn't fully utilize the CPU, you'll probably not gain anything from using threads.

Comment: I've two different algorithms, i do not know which is running faster, still i'm ending one. The first one uses about 50 % of cpu. The second one i'm still finishing uses about 10 % of cpu. I will compare time after 10 minutes, so that i can write here again. 

Thanks for the answwer about threads. A second question i have which dependicies effect to cpu usage ? How can i make same code running faster (change linking or change the code lines to increase calculating per step higher and so on ? )

Comment: If you do not know, you need to start profiling and measuring. There's no use in guessing, and we cannot tell you how to make things faster unless you describe what you are doing. Perhaps you're using the best agorithm for your problem already, or erhaps you're not and could use another algorithm, and gain 10% speed. Or 1000% speed.

Comment: thanks for remind me the measuring and profiling. i'm not sure if my algorithm is good, i shall finish and compare with the second one. thanks for advice !

Answer (score 1):

Using threads would be a viable solution if you had some way of parallelizing the task of building up the search tree.  This really depends on what sort of tree you're building.  If you're building some flavor of binary search tree, it might be possible, but you'll have to be careful to ensure that as you're inserting nodes you don't end up having any data races.  This probably would require each thread to acquire a lock on each node it visits.  If you're planning on using some sort of balanced tree (AVL, red/black, splay, AA, etc.) this is not likely to work very well, since the rotations could very easily interfere with other threads.

One option might be to split the work up.  There are implementations of balanced binary search trees that support fast merging (for example, some variants of red/black trees can be merged in O(lg n) time), which means that you could try splitting the data into groups, building up a balanced binary search tree from each group, then merging them all together into one balanced tree.  This would take advantage of parallelism.

Comment: i dont use binary trees. my tree has a depth of 7 and my branch factor changes between zero and 5000 [each depth has a lower branch] i'm working on an artifial intelligence program where there are over million possible states and over 50 thousand success states. that's why i have specialised my tree. I've increared the depth and added some constraints but my cpu has reduced, too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't have a CPU with 10 cores, so your program doesn't use all the CPU that it can and you have a different problem, like I/O access or something like that.

In this case use more thread is not the solution.

The tree search can be divided on threads easily (searching in the children by different threads for example), but as you are not using all the main thread capacity you don't obtain an better performance using more threads.

The CPU is not your program limiter

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look into the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to split your work up into several smaller tasks which can run at the same time.

Comment: vielen dank ! ich arbeite über .net 4.0; ich kann es schauen, aber ich habe nicht viel zeit es zu lernen :(

Comment: You're welcome and I appreciate, that you're writing in german to me. But could you please stick with english, so that the entire community can read this.

Comment: translation of my comment in german: thanks lot ! i'm working already on .net 4.0, i can look to task parallel library but i havent enough time to learn it now :(

Answer (score 0):

Running multi-threads doesn't mean use the CPU more, have a look on [parallel programming in .Net framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx).